# How to capture MIDI played on a Yamaha keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, audio, midi

I just bought a [Yamaha YPG-235](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalpianos/dgx_series/ypg-235/?mode=model) keyboard, Windows 7 doesn't seem to come with a tool like Garage Band for the Mac.

Is there free software that allows me to capture what I played?

Answer (score 2):

Reaper ( http://www.reaper.fm/ ) is a shareware Digital Audio Workstation package, which is not crippled while testing.

Answer (score 1):

Sony's [Acid xPress](http://www.acidplanet.com/downloads/xpress/) is free. :)

> ACID Xpress is a free, 10-track version of ACID software for music recording, editing and mixing. It's easy to use, even if you've never tried loop-based music creation before. Just pick some loops, paint them into a track and play them back. Any loops you choose work together because ACID Xpress matches the tempo and pitch automatically. When you're ready, publish your song to ACIDplanet.com

Includes In-line MIDI editing.  I've played with Acid Pro for years, it's MIDI capabilities are pretty nice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Garageband is very hard to work with MIDI. Id suggest Pro Tools First (it handles 16 channels of MIDI at a time). To learn more please visit https://www.avid.com/pro-tools/comparison

also, if you get more advanced and want something a little more professional later on, I'd recommend trying out Cubase LE AI Elements. It isn't free but I believe it is very inexpensive